# How to connect a button in the view to the db in code igniter?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am trying to connect a button in the view to the db. I know I have to use java script/ Ajax or jQuery  and the onclick(). But what should I do next? How do I connect the outcome of button click to a php variable which I can then save to the DB?

Update: (ANS)
What I was missing was the fact that controller can be accessed from view. Just do this:

```
<?php echo form_open('form/submit'); ?>
<br><br>
Title<br>
<input type="text" name="title"><br>
Body<br>
<input type="text" name="body">
<input type="submit" value="New">
```

This will submit the form back to the controller's submit function and you can do all you want with it. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: There are several ways to do this? One way is to connect to the db in the view but I am confused of the MVC model here as in where should I make a call to the db?

Comment: you should at least take a look at the [flow chart in CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html).

Comment: Ok it makes sense this is exactly why I am confused. We know that the input should only gets processed in the controller: We get user input from the view and pass it to the controller and controller calls the model. Am I right?

Comment: Once the view is rendered, the only way to make it give data to the controller is either form submission, another page request or AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view that handles ajax requests properly (probably just has JSON output)

and then make a request to it via AJAX from the view with the button.

Inside your ajax.php you can setup the appropriate code to access the db.

You're jquery / javascript ajax request is simply going to be in the View, it doesn't have it's own place in the MVC structure of codeigniter, from CI's perspective it's just two views.

Comment: Hebert Penito Is this safe way to connect to db? Can a malicious user just make similar calls? I thought the best way to handle any db calls in the MVC approach is to put any db call inside the model? Should I implement Ajax.php inside a model?

Comment: Well, it really depends on what you want to do after you connect to the db. Don't directly INSERT or UPDATE any of the REQUEST variables, because that's just asking for trouble. Usually db io functionality does go into the Model, but I suggest trying to figure out the requests intent in the controller, and then proceed to the appropriate action (function) that's located in the model. Typically, I like using SESSION variables to make sure that the request came from your site, like set a token and make sure it matches on both sides of the REQUEST (the page that made the request and ajax.php)